# User cannot upvote an answer to his question - why?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, privileges

The situation described in the title happened today - a user asked a question and received a good answer, but couldn't upvote it because he had a too low reputation (8 in this case).

I think it's rather odd that someone is not allowed to vote on answers to **his own** questions. Until today, I was sure it was allowed. In fact, when I answered (other) questions, and (other) askers didn't upvote my answers, I thought it was a somewhat grumpy behavior, and I guess other people think this way too.

Is there a reason to prevent low-reputation users from voting on answers to their questions?

Other similar actions low-reputation users can do:

- Comment on answers to their questions
- Choose an answer as accepted (obviously)

Why are low-reputation users specifically allowed to do these actions, but not vote?

Comment: Why so many -1's? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: It seems that people perceive this as a feature request - "please remove reputation limit on voting" - and want to say that they disagree

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Users can comment on their own questions without having sufficient reputation because it is an *essential* feature for them to interact with the site effectively.  Without being able to comment they wouldn't have the appropriate means to respond to feedback, provide feedback of their own to posts, etc.

Accepting an answer isn't a feature with a rep requirement waived for authors of a post.  It is simply a feature without a rep requirement at all, so the comparison doesn't apply.

Being able to vote on posts is not an essential feature for the author of a question.  They are not incapable of getting an answer as a result of not having access to that tool.  They even still have the ability to indicate that an answer is helpful to them in the form of acceptance, even without the ability to vote.

Comment: Now if only someone could get them to actually *accept* an answer instead of just commenting "hey thanks, that solved my problem" we'd be all set :)