# Why can't I downvote/flag completely incorrect answers to my own questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I understand why there's a reputation requirement to downvote posts -- it could easily be misused by new users or abused by trolls. However, it's rather frustrating as a low-reputation user that I can't downvote answers to my own question when they're unrelated or otherwise incorrect.

For example, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145136/queue-like-datastructure-that-is-readable-from-anywhere) question, I asked for help identifying a datastructure but received an answer using physics and collisions. It wasn't an answer to my question, it wasn't really even related to my question, and it wasn't well-explained. And yet, because I use this site too infrequently to gain any significant reputation, I had no way of marking it as unrelated, incorrect, or otherwise not at all answer.

I'm not asking for a feature change or such, but I'm curious as to the rationale behind this decision. According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277026/user-cannot-upvote-an-answer-to-his-question-why) post, the reason is because new users can still comment and mark an answer as accepted -- but there's no 0-rep equivalent to marking an answer as accepted for bad questions, and commenting does not always seem to get the point across. (In the case of [my given question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145136/queue-like-datastructure-that-is-readable-from-anywhere), for example, the answerer still insisted that his answer was relevant and correct.)

Comment: You asked for "some advice or examples".  That's what you got.  Be careful what you ask for.

Comment: Honestly, 125 reputation is not that much. It seems we've been both registered on SO for 1 year and 8 months so far. For a long time I felt the same way as you, lurking with 1 point of reputation, but once I started answering questions I got 125 rep in 3-4 days. But beware: it's fun and addictive!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are a few reasons for this. Here are some that come to mind.

First, new users don't always even know whether an answer is helpful, certainly not the way "helpful" is defined for upvoting purposes here. We see many posts every day in which it is clear that the author (1) thinks SO is a discussion-driven forum with threads and ongoing discussions and (2) does not understand how a Q&A site works. Not to mention the constant stream of questions on Meta about why something got upvoted or downvoted. We don't let new users vote on answers to their own questions for the same reason we don't let them vote anywhere else: it takes time to understand how this site works.

Second, many new users really have the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/238426). The best answers sometimes don't look anything like what the question's author expected.

Third, this is another layer of logic for what is, ultimately, a very small set of users: users who (1) have >=2 rep (because downvoting an answer costs 1 rep), (2) but have < 125, (3) who have posted a question, (4) have received an answer, (5) *understand how the site works and what downvotes are for*, and (6) want to downvote an answer at the expense of 1 rep. It's just not a major problem. Nor does giving OP this ability solve a particular problem; there are literally millions of other users, so truly bad answers tend to get the downvotes they deserve. It's not essential to give one particular user the power to downvote in order to serve the site's goal of making sure the best answers rise to the top.

Fourth, because lots of new users don't understand how a Q&A site (as opposed to a forum) works, there is a disproportionate amount of rage when new users feel like they aren't being helped the way they want. Existing users are less likely to help new users at all if they're worried about rage-downvotes when the new user gets frustrated.

Also, please be aware for the future that flags should not be used for incorrect answers. That's what downvotes are for. Flags are only for getting moderator attention for issues that *only* moderators can properly handle.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the issue with flags. I didn't know that.

Comment: If <125 rep users aren't qualified to judge the quality of answers, then why do they have the ability to accept an answer, a decision that is more powerful than a single vote; it can in fact overrule the entire community's consensus as to what the best answer is.  Additionally, your statement that this is a small subset of users is simply false.  A *huge* portion of questions are asked by <125 rep users.  It's nowhere *near* negligible.

Comment: @Servy Remember that accepting an answer does *not* mean that it is the "best" answer. It just means it's the answer that *the OP* found most helpful. That's not overriding a community consensus. And I didn't say <125 rep users post a small subset of questions. I said a small subset of questions (1) are posted by >=2 but <125 rep users, (2) have answers worth downvoting, and (3) were written by an OP who understands what a downvote is for. Put differently, as [Glorfindel pointed out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338285/2057919), this just isn't something the author of a question needs.

Comment: @EdCottrell Considering the site feels that the accepted answer should always show up at the top, it *is* treated as "the best answer".  If the site didn't feel it was the best answer, why would it always show up at the top, regardless of its score and the score of every other answer? If the OP is trusted to make that decision, why aren't they trusted to know whether or not an answer is helpful to them?  I'd argue that it very much *is* something that a question author needs.

Comment: @Servy Whether to pin accepted answers has been debated ad nauseum, as you know. That's not really relevant to this question, though. You're making an argument that accepting an answer shouldn't be left to OP. It isn't an argument to give new users even more power. No one strictly "needs" to be able to vote for anything, except for moderation purposes.

Comment: It's relevant in the sense that if the site feels that the author is trusted enough to do something *much* more influential than vote, that there can't really be an argument made that voting, a much less influential behavior in general, is something that we can't trust them to do.  While it wasn't the point of my earlier comments (nor did I say it) but I *do* feel that accepting gives too much power to question authors, voting gives them *exactly the right* amount of power.  They should be able to reflect their opinion of the quality of the post, just like anyone else in the community.

Comment: `No one strictly "needs" to be able to vote for anything, except for moderation purposes.`  Voting is an essential feature of the site, in my opinion.  The value of the site would be *dramatically* lower if the best answers didn't float towards the top, if users weren't given feedback as to the quality of their posts, if there wasn't a rough measure of quality to base other moderation actions on (automatic/manual deletion, post bans, etc.).  Voting, when combined with all of the other features that are entirely dependant on it, is integral to the success of the site.

Comment: @Servy Again, I didn't say the *community* doesn't need voting. I'm saying that's different from whether *a particular individual* needs the privilege of voting on *a particular post*. That said, I think we're talking past each other a bit. If you want to debate the merits of letting users in general or new users in particular accept an answer (or if you want to debate the value of showing the check mark, awarding 15 rep, or whatever), that should probably be in a new question, not in the comments here.

Comment: I'm *not* arguing for any change to the acceptance system (here).  I'm simply raising it as a point of comparison.  While not my opinion, the opinion of the system is that all question authors are trusted to decide what the best answer is for their question.  Given that, apparently, that is the general consensus of how much we trust them, it is contradictory to say that we don't trust them to indicate whether or not a given answer is useful or not useful.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough. I would point out, though, that there's a difference between saying "this answer . . . solved [my] problem or was the most helpful in finding [my] solution" (see the check mark mouseover text) and "This answer is not useful" (the down vote mouseover text). It's much easier (and usually requires much less knowledge) to figure out that an answer helped you than it is to determine that an answer is not helpful *at all*.

Comment: @EdCottrell I don't see how it's any more difficult.  If we trust them to determine if an answer *is* capable of solving their problem, then, by definition, they're capable of determining if an answer does *not* help them solve the problem.  If they try a solution presented, and it isn't capable of helping them solve the problem, then the answer is not useful to them solving the problem.  Done.  Of course, if other users feel that the answer is useful to them, then they can reflect that in *their* votes; the author downvoting it merely indicates that *to them* the answer wasn't useful.

Comment: Actually, SO _is_ a forum, just not a discussion forum. It is the very definition of a Q&A forum (anybody can ask and answer questions).

Comment: @RonMaupin In some sense, yes, it's a forum. But not in the sense that most internet users mean when they say that word. It doesn't, for example, have back-and-forth or multi-person discussions except for (1) a very limited and temporary amount of discussion in comments and (2) chat, which is a different animal altogether. Calling it a "Q&A forum" tends to create more confusion than it cures, at least in my experience.

Comment: As I wrote, it is _not_ a discussion forum. A courtroom is a forum, too, but it is definitely _not_ a discussion forum, either. A Q&A forum is where people can ask and answer questions, and that is the definition of what SO is. A Q&A forum need not be a discussion forum, re: a courtroom or SO, but you simply cannot say it's not a forum.

Comment: @Servy: Because the answer accept feature in its current state is straight up idiotic (what with pinning answers to the top, holding them hostage and so on). The only real reason it's there anymore is to make askers feel good about themselves - because other than noisy "thank you" comments they literally have no other means of acknowledging an answer to their own question when they have only 1 rep.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm not disagreeing with you that forum has lots of meanings. We are going to have to disagree, though, regarding whether SO is a forum in the sense that the overwhelming majority of users understand that word. This is a major issue with literally hundreds of users posting "me too" and new questions in the answers every day because they think it *is* like other forums. *My point is not that you're wrong to call it a forum.* My point is that, because SO is not like other sites, calling it a forum causes confusion. In any case, I've edited my answer to be a bit more precise.

Comment: We should absolutely eliminate the weight of the accept status. Maybe keep it to allow askers to reward helpful answers, but kill all of its power regarding deletion immunity, pinning, etc.

Comment: @AndrewMedico That makes sense to me. I think there's value in letting OP indicate which answer was most helpful *to OP* and attaching a reward to that, but it shouldn't be some magic talisman with superpowers.

Comment: @BoltClock `because other than noisy "thank you" comments they literally have no other means of acknowledging an answer to their own question when they have only 1 rep` That's one of the main reasons I'd like to see them able to vote on posts to their own question in that situation.  If they had that, then they wouldn't need to rely on the acceptance (at least, as much).

Answer (score 14):

The answer in the linked Meta question still applies:

> Being able to vote on posts is not an essential feature for the author of a question.

You indicated in a comment on the answer that it doesn't solve your problem. That serves as a signal to other people visiting your question that they can spend some effort in creating a new answer. If you didn't, they might assume you were satisfied with the answer and left the site. Being able to *comment* is therefore essential as an OP, but being able to vote isn't.

Comment: Votes are the intended mechanism for a user to indicate whether or not they feel a post is useful, not comments.  Votes exists as a mechanism precisely to prevent people from commenting merely to express their opinion of the quality of a post (as votes are much easier to consume).

Comment: @Servy right, but on a low-traffic question, a comment why an answer isn't useful, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145136/queue-like-datastructure-that-is-readable-from-anywhere#comment59959518_36146072), is *more* valuable than a downvote. And that's exactly what the OP can do.

Comment: In my experiences a post with a score of -10 and no comments explaining why it's an extremely poor solution to the problem tends to be used less than a +400 score answer with a comment under it explaining why its an extremely poor solution to the problem.  The first post never even gets ready by people looking for a solution (they'll simply end up reading an acceptable answer first, and never get to the bad answer) while in the case of the second answer *many* people won't take the time to read all of the comments before looking at the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's the other end of the spectrum. I added *on a low-traffic question* to be more precise.

Comment: On a low traffic question the author's vote has that much *more* weight though.  On a low traffic question the OP alone is quite likely to be able to decide whether the answer is positively or negatively scored.